# Regex to match words in next line

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regex to process text, which pretty much considers text if it’s in the same line, but ignores text if it starts from the next line. I tried adding \s* but that didn’t seem to work.

Can someone you please throw light on how can the regex be tuned for such condition

```
PATTERN = r’Section One:(\s?)[\t\f ]*[\w+]’
```

Input:

```
1. Section One:
 Gyjbhj jchhhhj jjgvbgg

2. Section Two: lknlknvd lknlfnv
lvkndflvlkvndflvkn
vlkfdnlkfn

3. Section Three:pklnklnfvl lknlknvl
flvkndflknvlf
```

Comment: Try splitting with `re.split(r'(?m)^\d+\.\s*', s)`

Comment: What do you expect the regexp to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metacharacter `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. That means it will match a linebreak `\n`. If you want to match any whitespace but the linebreak you have to state it explicitly by using the set `[ \t\r\f\v]`.

Although, it seems what you want to do is match sections of text starting with `'Section [some number]:'`. For this you can take advantage of the fact the `.` does not match linebreaks.

```
pattern = r'Section \w+:.*'
```

### Example

```
import re

text = """
1. Section One:
 Gyjbhj jchhhhj jjgvbgg

2. Section Two: lknlknvd lknlfnv
lvkndflvlkvndflvkn
vlkfdnlkfn

3. Section Three:pklnklnfvl lknlknvl
flvkndflknvlf"""

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

### Output

```
['Section One:', 'Section Two: lknlknvd', 'Section Three:pklnklnfvl']
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver, does this also consider if anynof those sections are left blank? In some cases it could be left empty. Basically the texts could be empty or in the same line or in the next line before each sections

Comment: @user16210528 I am not sure what you mean. Please add example of input-output. I merely guess what you wanted, you need to provide more details in the question for me to help further